# jQuery: make changes AFTER jQuery hide() is completed

Tags: jquery, html, hide, document-ready

Here is the problem: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DDeqU/)

What I want is the yellow height to be changed from 60px to 20px only **AFTER** it was slided down (it slides on click).  How to fix?

```
 $(document).ready(function ()
   {
     $('#slide-link').click(function(){
       $(this).animate({ top: $(window).height()-40 },5000)
       $('#sliderWrapper').stop().hide("slide", { direction:"down" }, 5000); 
       $('#slide-link').height(20)
      //I want 20px to become after #sliderWrapper slided down, not on click
      //That's why I put $('#slide-link').height(20) as the last line
      // But it triggers asap. How to fix?
    })
})​
```

As far as I see, `$('#slide-link').height(20)` does NOT wait until `$('#sliderWrapper').stop().hide("slide", { direction:"down" }, 5000);`
is finished.

P.S. `$('#slide-link').delay(5000).height(20)` does NOT help either. Why? How to fix?

Comment: as in http://jsfiddle.net/DDeqU/1/ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`.delay()` only affects functions that use the animation queue. However, `.height()` is not animation-related at all and thus doesn't use that queue.

What you want is the callback of `.hide()` which triggers after the animation has completed:

```
$('#sliderWrapper').stop().hide("slide", {
    direction: "down"
}, 5000, function() {
    $('#slide-link').height(20)
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThiefMaster/DDeqU/3/